# Netty 3.2.6 - less readablebytes

Tags: java, netty

I am using 3.2.6 (I know its way too old but current project constraints does not allow me to upgrade till next two months) for one of server solution. I do not have control over client.

We have a framedecoder in pipeline to handle the custom message which has a header and body. One of the header fields contains the length of the body. For a specific message, I get a size of 1076 bytes. But while getting the message, I always get 1024 bytes (readableBytes()) and hence decoder fails.

I checked with wireshark (with suitable dissector for the protcol). The client always sends 1076 bytes and puts the same value on the header. So, client does not seem to misbehave.

My receive buffer size is already set to higher value as following on server bootstrap with no apparent effect.

```
bootstrap.setOption("child.receiveBufferSize", 1*1024*1024);
```

This is seen consistently only for this specific message and all other messages (whose sizes range from 100 to 1000 bytes) are handled correctly without any issues.

Please let me know what else could cause this issue and how to fix the same?

Comment: I think sharing some parts of your framedecoder would be helpful. Check your `decode` method to make sure you read as much bytes as you need before processing further. 'DECODER IMPLEMENTATION' example in this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.1/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/codec/frame/FrameDecoder.html) might be helpful.

Comment: @wns349, as you hint,  I just noticed that when sufficient bytes are not read, I am currently returning a non-null message in decode method. I am now trying with returning null until required length is not extracted fully so that Netty handles the same and escalates to decoder only when all required bytes are read. I will post the observations and also the code. Thanks